# Cannot run any ROS command in jenkins job

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ros

So what I want to do is just to run "rospack list" in jenkins job. My Jenkinsfile is quite simple:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
             sh '. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash'
             sh 'rospack list'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Neither the source command nor the rospack can be run inside jenkins job. But when I log in with jenkins account and do the same things as listed above, it works. So I am really confused what is wrong with the Jenkinsfile. Thanks for help in advance!

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Jenkins: 2.150.3
- ROS: kinetic

[image: Error info from Jenkins job].
[image: Test with jenkins account]

Comment: And still a very strange issue is that when I create a free-style job, then execute the script as build step, then it works. That means the problem is only with pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this problem myself today.
The reason `sh '. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash'` fails is because `setup.bash` is intended to be executed by *bash*, but here it is invoked using *sh*.

Luckily ROS also provides a setup file for use with `sh`, so if you amend the above command as follows, it should execute successfully:

`sh '. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

OK, as far as I understand, one sh command is executed in one terminal, so the sourced PATH will not be taken by the second sh command. It works when using /bin/bash instead of '.':

```
**test.sh**
#! /bin/bash
. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
rospack list

**Jenkinsfile**
pipeline {
 agent any
 stages {
   stage('Test') {
     steps {
          sh '/bin/bash /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash'
     }
   }
 }
```

}